# updating function called by updateIn() returns an immutable object instead of value

Tags: jestjs, enzyme, immutable.js, react-boilerplate

We have a react-boilerplate setup, which uses ImmutableJS, Jest and Enzyme as part of its framework.

We have come across an issue when testing reducer using **ImmutableJS's** [updateIn()](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/updateIn).

The page works OK, but we are unable to test it, as in reducer test, the immutable updater function receives immutable object, but we are expecting a plain JS object to operate with.

**reducer.js:**

```
case ACTION_TYPE: {

  const targetSectionId = action.sectionId;
  return state.updateIn(['allSections'], (allSections) =>

    allSections.map((section) => {

      // section is wrapped in immutable when testing
      // on regular execution, section.get() will fail
      // as it is plain javascript object
      const updatedSection = Object.assign({}, section);
      const sectionIdMatched = updatedSection.sectionId === targetSectionId;

      if (sectionIdMatched) {
        // on tests, does not get here
        // on regular execution, we get here
        updatedSection.commonSectionNames = action.commonSections;
        return updatedSection;
      }
      return updatedSection;
    })

  );

}
```

=============

**reducer.test.js:**

```
it('should handle the action correctly', () => {
  // arrange

  const sectionId = 15;
  const valueToSet = ['fixture'];
  const initialState = fromJS({
     allSections: [{ sectionId: 15, commonSectionNames: [] }]
  });
  const expectedState = fromJS({
     allSections: [{ sectionId: 15, commonSectionNames: valueToSet }] 
  });


  // act
  const result = reducer(initialState, action(sectionId, valueToSet));


  // assert
  expect(result).toEqual(expectedState);
});
```

============

Any advise with this is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

That is just the way it is. immutable updater function will receive immutable object. If you need plainJS object, use [toJS()](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map/toJS) like this:

```
allSections.map((tempSection) => {
    const section = tempSection.toJS();
// perform operations with plainJS "section" here
```